# pushStates / S3 : refreshing the page

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I have a SPA (Single Page Application) exposed on a S3 server on which I have no control.

It has its (front) routing based on history pushstates in html5 mode.
Everything is in an "index.html" page.

Which means that `http://example.com:8080/myapp` shows an app with links pointing for example to `http://example.com:8080/myapp/about/me` without having a "about" folder : everything is powered by Javascript.

But, if the user refreshes the page `http://example.com:8080/myspa/about/me`, he will get a 404.

So I decided to put in place a reverse proxy.

What I tried so far :

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ http://example.com:8080/myapp/index.html;
        #proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/myapp/;
    }
}
```

With those rules, I can reverse proxy to the app but unfortunately, It doesn't work.

How can a reverse proxy to an app exposing an "index.html" with Javascript routes based on pushstates and allowing the user to refresh the page correctly ?

Comment: This is not an "S3 server."  It looks like Nginx.